# NullPointerException in send email verification, Android studio with google firebase

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

So the situation is my code was working fine untill I started making other activity. After I run my project again to try to register it displayed this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ius, PID: 19023
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ius.Registracija$2.onComplete(Registracija.java:92)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

here is my code where it shows problem:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailS,passwordS).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful()){
               user.sendEmailVerification()
                       .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                   Toast.makeText(Registracija.this, "Registered successfully, Please verify your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   dialog.dismiss();
                                   startActivity(new Intent(Registracija.this,MainActivity.class));
                               }
                           }
                       });
           }
           else {
               Toast.makeText(Registracija.this, "An error occurred please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               dialog.dismiss();
               return;
           }
       }
   });
```

I thought the problem was when I changed variables id, because for some reason id for email in 2 activities were connected.
Any help/tip would be great, thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is null therefore try the following:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailS,passwordS).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful()){
              FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
              user.sendEmailVerification()
                       .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
```

Use the `getCurrentUser()` to retrieve the logged in user and then call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `user.sendEmailVerification()` and apparently `user` is null. After you've created a new user, you should read the user from the `AuthResult` of the task.

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
    task.getResult().getUser().sendEmailVerification()
```